# 'ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I have a Convolutional Neural Network in tensorflow with 6 hidden layers, right now I have two classes for the classification but in the final dense layer (softmax activation function). Since I have two classes I need two neurons in the output layer but whenever I put two I get the error:

' ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))'

However, it works fine with one neuron.

This is my code for creating the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import os
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


train_imgdata=[]
train_classes=[]
test_imgdata=[]
test_classes=[]


TYPE={"Dataset/Train", "Dataset/Validate"}
Category={"Glaucoma", "Non-Glaucoma"}







def GetData():
    for n, tpe in enumerate(TYPE):
        if n==0:
            for i, cat in enumerate(Category):
                clss=i
                OGpath=os.path.join(tpe,cat)
                print (OGpath)
                for file in os.listdir(OGpath):
                    filepath=os.path.join (OGpath, file)
                    image=cv2.imread(filepath)
                    image_resized=cv2.resize(image,(1700,1300))
                    train_imgdata.append(image_resized)
                    train_classes.append(clss)

        else:
            
            for i, cat in enumerate(Category):
                clss=i
                OGpath=os.path.join(tpe,cat)
                print (OGpath)
                for file in os.listdir(OGpath):
                    filepath=os.path.join (OGpath, file)
                    image=cv2.imread(filepath)
                    image_resized=cv2.resize(image,(1700,1300))
                    test_imgdata.append(image_resized)
                    test_classes.append(clss)
                    

            
def plot_history (training):
    axs[0].plot(training.history["accuracy"], label="train accuracy")
    axs[0].plot(training.history["val_accuracy"], label="validation accuracy")
    axs[0].set_ylabel("Accuracy")
    axs[0].setlegend(loc="lower right")
    axs[0].set.set_title("Accuracy_eval")
        
        
   
        
        
        
        
        
def CreateModel(InShape):

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential() 

 

    # 1st conv layer 

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1300, 1700,3), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))) 

    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')) 
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)) 
    

 

    # 2nd conv layer 

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 

    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')) 
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)) 
 

 

    # 3rd conv layer 

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (2, 2), activation='relu')) 

    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')) 
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)) 
 

 

    # flatten output and feed it into dense layer 

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten()) 

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')) 

    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)) 

 

    # output layer 

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')) 

 

    return model 

 

 

 

 
    

    
if __name__=="__main__":
    
    
    GetData()
    real_train_imgdata=np.array(train_imgdata)
    
    real_train_classes=np.array(train_classes)
    
    real_test_imgdata=np.array(test_imgdata)
    
    real_test_classes=np.array(test_classes)
    
        
    inputshape=(real_train_imgdata.shape[1], real_train_imgdata.shape[2], real_train_imgdata.shape[3])
    
    
    
    model=CreateModel(inputshape)
    
    optimiser= keras.optimizers.Adam (learning_rate=0.001)
    
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser,
                 loss="binary_crossentropy",
                 metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.summary()
    
    
    model.fit(real_train_imgdata, real_train_classes, validation_data=(real_test_imgdata, real_test_classes), batch_size=3, epochs=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a single scalar for your train_classes/test_classes values, which is just the category index (0 or 1), but your model is separately predicting a likelihood for each of the two classes. You can either change to using a single output from your model (so 0 if 'Glaucoma', 1 if 'Non-Glaucoma' or vice versa) or use an array of two values ([1, 0] or [0, 1]) for the target values you pass into model.fit(). This second approach is a simple example of what's called 'one-hot encoding'.

Comment: But how is it calculating the likelihood of both classes using just one neuron on the output, does it just calculate the probability of one and figure out the other? Also, what would be the benefit of using one-hot encoding in this scenario over the other? and finally, I thought my model was creating only a single output by using the most probable option from the output layer, is it not/what is it actually doing. P.S. Sorry for all the questions, and thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: The test data you're using appears to be a binary classification, 'Glaucoma' or 'Non-Glaucoma'. If that's the case you only need a single output, let's say using the 'Glaucoma' case as 1 so that the output value can be considered the probability of a specific sample being from the 'Glaucoma' class.

For a binary classification problem there's probably no benefit in using two outputs rather than one. If you add more classes (say 'Open-angle Glaucoma', 'Closed-angle Glaucoma', and 'Normal-tension Glaucoma') you'll need to switch to multiple outputs.